# ImageObserver Class not found

Tags: java

So i have an image being drawn inside a void method in my main class, and every tutorial i have looked at has told me to just write 'this' in the last field of the drawImage() method.
Unfortunately, obviously since this is inside a void method, 'this' does not work.

How do I deal with this?
Is there a way to create a local ImageObserver variable?
I dont need to use it really.

Code snippets:

```
URL iurl = new URL("cyn.png"); 
Image bi = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(iurl);

graphics.drawImage(bi,d.width/2+10,110,128,128,iob);
```

i dont know what else i need to show
i imported the Image class and graphics class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***How do I deal with this? Is there a way to create a local ImageObserver variable? I dont need to use it really.***

If you don't need to *use* the image observer, you can safely pass `null` as argument. (It's basically only used when loading images asynchronously.)

From [The Java™ Tutorials: Drawing an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html):

> *The observer parameter notifies the application of updates to an image that is loaded asynchronously. The observer parameter is not frequently used directly and is not needed for the BufferedImage class, so it usually is null.*